# How to detect user window resize vs window.resizeTo

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a window with many fields, some of these fields show/hide other fields or elements in the view. When this happens I call a function to adjust the window size.

That function basically gets the body width and height and resizes the window accordingly using window.resizeTo function.

Now I've been asked to add a new feature:
If the user resizes the window manually, stop further automatic resizing.

I figure I can listen to the resize event and maybe detect when it's been triggered by the window.resizeTo function and when it's been triggered by the user.

The problem is, I haven't found a way... Is it possible?

Comment: Is there some overarching reason you are jumping through so many hoops top present your data? I can't imagine a situation where I'm having to manually adjust window size based on content. Sounds like a potential UX risk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [`.resize()`](http://api.jquery.com/resize/). But I don't see a change to get a native information from the browser if the window was resized by the user. But I could think of a solution where you set a flag when your function resizes the window* and then do nothing inside .resize(). But if .resize() is fired but your flag was not set, It was triggered by the user.

* = also remove the flag after your resize code ran.

Comment: This works but you have to be careful using the resize  event listener as JS triggers that event many times per resize. You have to use a debounced resize event listener, there is a jQuery plugin I used to solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're correct, using the "resize" event you can detect when a user is resizing their browser.
Example:

```
document.addEventListener("resize", function(){
  alert("resizing!");
}, false);
```